# Possible incorrect implementation of Double-check locking

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread safe class:

```
internal class ExmplFile 
{
    private readonly string filename;
    private int resolution;
    private volatile PaddedImage gaussian;
    private object lockObject=new object();

    //blah, blah, blah

    internal PaddedImage Gaussian()
    {
        if (gaussian != null)
        {
            return gaussian;
        }
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (gaussian == null)
            {
                Image();
                if (File.Exists(filename + "-gaus.raw"))
                {
                    gaussian = LoadImage(filename + "-gaus.raw", TerraGodContext.Instance()
                        .Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    gaussian.ConformRepeatPadding();
                }
                else
                {
                    gaussian = new PaddedImage(resolution, resolution, false, 
                        TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    PaddedImage temp = new PaddedImage(resolution, resolution, false, 
                        TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    ImageProcessing.CalcGaussian(image,gaussian,temp, 16f* resolution
                        /TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.ExmplResDS);
                }
            }
        }
        return gaussian;
    }

}
```

Resharper gives me three warnings:

1. On gaussian in `gaussian.ConformRepeatPadding()` it says ***Possible incorrect implementation of Double-check locking. Read access to checked field.***.
2. On gaussian in `gaussian = new PaddedImage(` it says ***Possible incorrect implementation of Double-check locking. Possible multiple write access to checked field.***.
3. On gaussian in `ImageProcessing.CalcGaussian(image,gaussian,temp,` it says ***Possible incorrect implementation of Double-check locking. Read access to checked field.*** (The same warning as number 1).

Am I being silly or Resharper is?

**PS:** In case I've missed something important, here is the full class code with parts I omitted above.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace UPlus.TerrEngine
{
internal class ExmplFile : IEquatable<ExmplFile>
{
    private readonly string filename;
    private int resolution;
    private volatile PaddedImage image;
    private volatile PaddedImage gaussian;
    private object lockObject=new object();
    public ExmplFile(string abstractFileName, int res)
    {
        filename = new StringBuilder(abstractFileName).Append("-").Append(res.ToString("D4")).ToString();
        resolution = res;
    }

    internal FilledList<MatchItem>[] GetMatchItems(int groupIdx, int regionIdx)
    {
        AlgorithmConfig Config = TerraGodContext.Instance().Config;
        if (resolution !=Config.ExmplResDS) throw new Exception();
        PpaGraph exmplGraph = new PpaGraph(Config.ExmplResDS, Config.ExmplResDS, Config.ExmplResDS
            / Config.PpaExmplResDS);
        exmplGraph.Calculate(Image(), true, false, DebugOpts.BranchMin);
        exmplGraph.PrepareGraphForMatch(Config.ExmplCptRadius, Config.ExmplProcNodeDistance);
        exmplGraph.CalcExmplProcNodeGroups(groupIdx);
        MatchItemFinder matchItemFinder=new MatchItemFinder(Image(),Config.ExmplPatchSizeDS,true);
        matchItemFinder.Init(exmplGraph.processNodesGroups, regionIdx);
        return matchItemFinder.matchItems;
    }

    internal FastList<MatchItem> LoadMatchItems()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    internal PaddedImage Image()
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            return image;
        }
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (image == null)
            {
                image=LoadImage(filename + ".raw", TerraGodContext.Instance().Config
                    .PpaCandidateRange);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
    internal PaddedImage Gaussian()
    {
        if (gaussian != null)
        {
            return gaussian;
        }
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (gaussian == null)
            {
                Image();
                if (File.Exists(filename + "-gaus.raw"))
                {
                    gaussian = LoadImage(filename + "-gaus.raw", TerraGodContext.Instance()
                        .Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    gaussian.ConformRepeatPadding();
                }
                else
                {
                    gaussian = new PaddedImage(resolution, resolution, false, 
                        TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    PaddedImage temp = new PaddedImage(resolution, resolution, false, 
                        TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.PpaCandidateRange);
                    ImageProcessing.CalcGaussian(image,gaussian,temp, 16f* resolution
                        /TerraGodContext.Instance().Config.ExmplResDS);
                }
            }
        }
        return gaussian;
    }

    private PaddedImage LoadImage(string fileName, int padding)
    {
        PaddedImage img=new PaddedImage(resolution,resolution,false,padding);
        img.LoadRaw(fileName);
        img.ConformRepeatPadding();
        return img;
    }

    public bool Equals(ExmplFile other)
    {
        return filename == other.filename;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return filename.GetHashCode();
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is a screenshot in case the situation is not clear:

[image]

Comment: This is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/ReadAccessInDoubleCheckLocking.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/PossibleMultipleWriteAccessInDoubleCheckLocking.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, within the `lock`, you should use local variables and make the write to the checked field the *last* possible action.

Otherwise, what are you doing to it in the middle? E.g. what does `ConformRepeatPadding()` do? I'm guessing it has side effects since it has no return value? But by the time you call it, you've *already* exposed that object by assigning it's value to the field.

Other threads may be able to observe this object in a "partially constructed" state if you assign to the field too early, so as I say, you should generally make the write to the field the last possible action inside the `lock`.

Comment: Yes ConformRepeatPadding() changes the state of gaussian. I didn't think of it that way since this method is the only way to get the gaussian field. Thanks to you now I get the reason and it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, the local variable approach is valid, but I think Lazy<T> was designed to make bugs like this less likely to occur

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your property using [Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Your code looks correct, but that should get rid of the error and is a framework pattern for exactly this kind of thing

Comment: Nice catch. Yes I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange with your lock. I've alwais seen it on static lock object and not private object.
If your class isn't singleton, your lock alwais pass through as no lock was made.

Comment: No it's not a singleton and I think using instance objects as lock monitor is completely valid .

Comment: yes, is valid until all concurrent thread use that instance for monitor concurred resource.  if instance is thread dependend lock variable isn't shared and so no thread will wait any other thread